# Metrics from Spring Boot are not showing up in Prometheus

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, code-metrics

Followed steps given below to send Metrics from Spring Boot to Prometheus:

**Note**: I have installed Prometheus locally on my Mac using a Docker image.

1. In pom.xml added this:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Micormeter core dependecy  -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
       <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.6</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
       <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In application.properties added this:

> ```
> server.port: 9000
> management.server.port: 9001
> management.server.address: 127.0.0.1
>
> management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
> management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
> management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
> ```

3. Started Prometheus with following lines in configuration file:

Global configurations

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     5s # Set the scrape interval to every 5 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 5s # Evaluate rules every 5 seconds.
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'hello-world-promethus'
  metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9001']
```

When I hit: http://localhost:9001/actuator/prometheus, I can see the metrics but they are not visible on Prometheus UI.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution was simple. You will run into this only if you're running Prometheus Docker Container. Changed target from: 'localhost:9001' to 'docker.for.mac.localhost:9001'. For example:

```
- job_name: hello-world-promethus
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - docker.for.mac.localhost:9001
```

Comment: The more I work with docker, the more I like it. I hope there are not surprises on production.